# ArrayList computation?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I add the units he/she enrolled every time the user inputs the code he/she wants to enroll? Is there any way I can add the units every time he/she enroll using arrayList?

```
   int units = 3 
    arrList.add("A25"+"\t\tCS 212"+"\t\tData Structures\t\t\t\t"+ units);
    arrList.add("A26"+"\t\tIT 312"+"\t\tData Base Management System 2\t\t"+ units);
    arrList.add("A27"+"\t\tIT 312"+"\t\tData Base Management System 2\t\t"+ units);

  System.out.println("\n\t\tCodes to enroll");
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++,num++)
    {   
       codeNo[i] = scan.next();
    }
   for (String s : arrList) {

            for(int i =0; i < codeNo.length; i++)

                  if (s.startsWith(codeNo[i])) {

                    System.out.println("\t\t\t"+s);


                  /**
                   *  this is what I tried
                   * units = units + units;
                   */
                  } 

            }
     tuitionFee = ( tuitionFee * units  + miscFee )  / 3;

        System.out.println("\n\n\t\tTOTAL FEE: ");
        System.out.printf("\t\tPrelims: "+"%.2f",tuitionFee);
        System.out.printf("\t\tMidTerm: "+"%.2f",tuitionFee);
        System.out.printf("\t\tFinals: "+"%.2f",tuitionFee);
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear

Comment: What are the "units" exactly? The number of courses?

Comment: @Henri the units of that subject

Comment: I think what you want is a HashMap that convert code into units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap<String,Integer> mapCodeToUnit = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
mapCodeToUnit.put("A25", 3);
mapCodeToUnit.put("A26", 3);
mapCodeToUnit.put("A27", 3);


arrList.add("A25"+"\t\tCS 212"+"\t\tData Structures\t\t\t\t"+ mapCodeToUnit.get("A25"));
arrList.add("A26"+"\t\tIT 312"+"\t\tData Base Management System 2\t\t"+ mapCodeToUnit.get("A26"));
arrList.add("A27"+"\t\tIT 312"+"\t\tData Base Management System 2\t\t"+ mapCodeToUnit.get("A27"));

System.out.println("\n\t\tCodes to enroll");
String codeNo[] = new String[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++,num++)
{   
    codeNo[i] = scan.next();
}

int totalNumberOfUnit = 0;
for(int i =0; i < codeNo.length; i++) {
   totalNumberOfUnit += mapCodeToUnit.get(codeNo[i]);
}

tuitionFee = ( tuitionFee * totalNumberOfUnit  + miscFee )  / 3;
```

Comment: Thanks It didn't get the answer precisely but I think I get it now.  I think I have to learn to how use HashMap. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of `EntrollmentDTO` instead of list of `String`

`EntrollmentDTO.java`

```
class EntrollmentDTO {
    private String id;
    private String subId;
    private String subName;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Make a List of `EntrollmentDTO` as,

```
ArrayList<EntrollmentDTO> entrollmentList = new ArrayList<EntrollmentDTO>();
```

And add details as,

```
EntrollmentDTO entrollmentDTO = new EntrollmentDTO();
entrollmentDTO.setId("A25");
// set all values

entrollmentList.add(entrollmentDTO);
```

By this you can easily access needed values from the list.